# Why is Rails' asset cache not working for JS in the staging environment?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, caching

I have my CSS and JS set to cache in `RAILS_ROOT/app/views/layouts/application.html.erb`:

```
<%= stylesheet_link_tag 'reset', ...
                        'layout', 'colors', :cache => 'cache/all' %>
<%= javascript_include_tag 'jquery-1.3.2.min', ...
                           'application', :cache => 'cache/all' %>
```

If I turn on caching in my development environment, everything works as planned:

```
# in RAILS_ROOT/config/environments/development.rb:
config.action_controller.perform_caching = true
```

When I put the same line in staging, though, `/stylesheets/cache/all.css` is generated properly, but `/javascripts/cache/all.css` isn't.  The line is generated in the HTML as though it were, though:

```
<script src="/javascripts/cache/all.js?1253556008" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Going to that URL yields an empty JS file (though not a 404, oddly). There is no file on the file-system (under `RAILS_ROOT/public/javascripts/cache/all.js`).

Any thoughts?

Comment: Silly question, but presumably you've enabled caching in config/environments/staging.rb?

Comment: Yeah - that's how I got the CSS file to cache properly. And Rails certainly _thinks_ caching should be on for both as it generates the /all.js and /all.css tags in the staging HTML.

Comment: I'm also having the same problem, deleting the file was no help, it just rebuilt an empty file.

Answer (score 3):

It's a long shot but try deleting the all.js file and see if the app rebuilds it correctly. Once the file is in place Rails seems to never try to rebuild it, so if it was badly formed because of some bug or whatnot it may have been left there.

Comment: It's been too long since I've had this problem, but this is a great recommendation for debugging if I come across is again.

Comment: Worked for me! I had an issue where it was serving up an old file after deploying multiple times and deleting the cached file seems to have fixed it.